# XPath retrieving values from multiple tags inside a node

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm currently creating a crawler and I'm at the point where I need to abstract data in a set so I can send it to a database as a single row, nice and neat.

Here is a snip-it of my program, it correctly goes to each page so far and retrieves the correct corresponding url

```
int tempflag = 0;
//linkValueList is full of sub urls previously crawled in the program
foreach (string str in linkValueList)
{
    string tempURL = baseURL + str;
    HtmlWeb tempWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument tempHtml = tempWeb.Load(tempURL);
    foreach (HtmlNode node in tempHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//article[@itemprop='product']"))
    {
        //get the category from the linkNameList
        string tempCategory = linkNameList.ElementAt(tempflag);
        //grab url
        string tempHref = node.GetAttributeValue("data-itemurl", string.Empty);
       //grab image url
       //grab brand
       //grab name
       //grab price
       //send to database via INSERT
    }
    tempflag++;
}
```

Here is the site code I am working with, this is an example of one item, each item looks similar

```
<article .... itemprop="product" data-itemurl="Item's url">
    <figure>
        <a ....>
            <img .... src="item's image source" ...>
        </a>
        <div ...>
            <a>....</a>
        </div>
    </figure>
    <div ...>
        <a ....>
                <div class="brand" itemprop="brand>Item's Brand</div>
            <div class="title" itemprop="name">Item's Name</div>
        </a>
        <div ....>
            <div class="msrp"></div>
            <div class="price" itemprop="price">$18.99 - $119.99</div>
            <span ...> ... </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

As you can see I have already used XPath to get myself inside of the `<article>` tag to get the `data-itemurl` to retrieve the item's url. My question is now that I am already inside of the `<article>` tag, is there an easy way to now access the other tags nested inside?

I need to get to the `<img>` tag for the image's url, `<div itemprop="brand">` for the brand, `<div itemprop="name">` for the item name, and `<div itemprop="price">` for the price.

As I mentioned before, I am trying to get all of that information in one go around so I can query it all into a database as a single insert statement at the end of each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can use another XPath to query within a given element. One thing to note, which many have been troubled with, never start a relative XPath with `/`, for it will search the entire document instead, start with `./` if you need to, for example (`SelectSingleNode()` assumed to always find the target element here, otherwise you need to check whether the result is not `null` first) :

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in tempHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//article[@itemprop='product']"))
{
    img = node.SelectSingleNode(".//img").GetAttributeValue("src","");
    brand = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@itemprop='brand']").InnerText.Trim();
    .....
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I was trying to get into those myself for days, I was close but didn't have the correct XPath syntax. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use `node.Descendants("img")` or `node.Descendants("div").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("itemprop") && d.Attributes["itemprop"].Value.Equals("price"))`

Hope it helps.